# Find a solution for this homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra, homogeneous-equation

$$3a+2b+c+3d+5e=0\\
6a+4b+3c+5d+7e=0\\
9a+6b+5c+7d+9e=0\\
3a+2b+4d+8e=0$$

After using Gauss elimination method, I have
\begin{bmatrix}
3&2&1&3&5\\ 
0&0&1&-1&-3\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}

Even though I have 1 free variable(5varibales-4equations), I don't know how to solve to get all of the a,b,c,d,e. Please help me how to continue.
Thank you all in advance .

Comment: Keep going in elimination, subtract row 1 from row 2.

Comment: i keep going in elimation and i got ( 3a+2b=-4d-2e ->c=d-3e-> which ends up 0 =0 .

Comment: I meant do all steps until matrix in row reduced echelon form. Look up row reduced echelon form to see what next to do in solving system.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Using Gauss-Jordan elimination:

First, set up the matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}3&2&1&3&5\\6&4&3&5&7\\9&6&5&7&9\\3&2&0&4&8\end{bmatrix}$$

Then, replace $R_2-2R_2\rightarrow R_2, R_3-3R_1\rightarrow R_3, R_4-R_1\rightarrow R_4$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}3&2&1&3&5\\0&0&1&-1&-3\\0&0&2&-2&-6\\0&0&-1&1&3\end{bmatrix}$$
The, replace $R_1-R_2\rightarrow R_1, R_3-2R_2\rightarrow R_3, R_2+R_4\rightarrow R_4$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}3&2&0&4&8\\0&0&1&-1&-3\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

You are left with the following system of equations:
$$3a+2b+4d+8e=0$$$$c-d-3e=0$$

This can be rearranged to form:
$$4d+8e=-3a-2b$$$$d+3e=c$$

Now you can choose any values you'd like for $a,b,c$.  Based on these values, there will be one possible set of values for $d$ and $e$:
$$d=-\frac{8c+9a+6b}{4}$$
$$e=\frac{3a+2b+4c}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail explanation.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, you can delete the last two rows of your matrix; you can also "mark" the columns. The ones that have a leading nonzero entry for some row are marked "D" for "dependent", the others are marked "I". So in your case, we get to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
D&I&D&I&I\\
3&2&1&3&5\\ 
0&0&1&-1&-3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
That means that the variables $a$ and $c$ are dependent, and $b, d, e$ are independent. In other words, you can pick ANY value you like for $b,d,e$, and then find $a$ and $c$ from the two equations. For instance, if we pick $(b, d, e) = (1,0,0)$, we get that
$$
3a + 2b + c + 3d + 5e = 3a + 2 + c + 0 + 0 = 3a + 2 + c = 0
$$
and
$$
c - d - 3e = c - 0 = 3\cdot 0 = c = 0$$

which we can now solve, bottom up, to get that $c = 0$ and $3a + 2 = 0$ so $a = -2/3$.

Now you could do this for *any* $b,d,e$ triple and get a solution, and in fact this gives all *possible* solutions, but you can get them all at once by rewriting the two equations a little differently. First, through, I want to do one more elimination step, which is to use the "1" in row 2, col 3, to remove the numbers *above* it as well as below, so we subtract the second row from the first to get

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
D&I&D&I&I\\
3&2&0&4&8\\ 
0&0&1&-1&-3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that our equations are now
$$
c - d - 3e = 0 \\
a + 2b + 4d + 8e = 0
$$
which I'm going to rewrite by bringing everything except $a$ and$c$ to the other side:
$$
c = d + 3e\\
a =  -2b - 4d - 8e
$$
Now you can see that any solution looks like
$$
\pmatrix{a\\b\\c\\d\\e} = \pmatrix{-2b-4d-8e\\b\\d + 3e \\ d \\ e}.
$$
And that's it --- that's the solution to the whole problem.

NB: All this was done assuming that your original row-reduced matrix was correct; it appears not to be. The good news is that you can now carry out the analogous computations yourself, and test that you understand the general method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- There are $5$ unknowns and $4$ equations so there are a lot of solutions (an obvious one is the zero solution). But doing $x = 3a + 2b$ we obtain the following system of $4$ equations with $4$ unknowns:
$$x+c+3d+5e=0\\
2x+3c+5d+7e=0\\
3x+5c+7d+9e=0\\
x+4d+8e=0$$ which can be solved with any of the usual methods.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer I really appreciate it

Comment: You are welcome. Good Luck.